# Why migration is empty?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I execute the migration command "add-migration", but I find that the class is without code.

there is some way to generate the code or do I have to write it by myself?

[image]

Comment: Dear @ZinelabidineBacha, you should not write it yourself. This might be because there's no change since the last migration. Or if you're added a new model, ensure to implement it in dbcontext. If these solve your problem, please let me know

Comment: no does not work

Comment: Check out your migrations in their folder. This problem might happen if you have ran this command twice by accident, or run update_database and check if it is up to date or not

Comment: i try to delete the "Migrations" folder and i do again the command "add-migration" , but does not work

Comment: Is there any error occured? what nuget packages have you installed?

Comment: No Error , Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
, design , sqlServer ...

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your scenario. It is because of the DBcontext.
When DBcontext is like below

```
public class WebApplication18Context : DbContext
    {
        public WebApplication18Context (DbContextOptions<WebApplication18Context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<WebApplication18.Student> Student;
    }
```

'add-migration' will generate an empty migration class.
But after you add  `{ get; set; } = default!;` to `DbSet` It will work as noraml.

```
public class WebApplication18Context : DbContext
    {
        public WebApplication18Context (DbContextOptions<WebApplication18Context> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<WebApplication18.Student> Student { get; set; } = default!;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Not having DbSet<T> _properties_ is one of the many ways one can trigger an empty migration. Another one is to simply not have changes to entities or context since the latest migration.